# How to direct linux bash script output to one line per host

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to change my script(s) so that the command output is separated by a comma and is all on one line per host.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this:

1st Script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat ~/hostnames.txt`
do
        ssh -q $i 'bash -s' < server_info.sh
done
```

2nd Script (server_info.sh):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Name: "
uname -n
echo -n "CPUs: "
cat /proc/cpuinfo* | grep processor | wc -l
echo -n "Memory (kb): "
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal: | awk '{print $2}'
echo -n "Current Kernel: "
uname -a | awk '{print $3}'
echo -n "IP: "
hostname -i
echo -e
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing your `1st script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in cat ~/hostnames.txt
do
        ssh -q $i 'bash -s' < server_info.sh 
done | awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'
```

Note: Your `server_info.sh` can be a lot more optimized.For example:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal: | awk '{print $2}'
```

could be changed to:

```
awk '/MemTotal:/{print $2}' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: I've added a tick, is that the way to accept the answer?

Comment: Why not `xargs` instead of  `awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1'`!?

Comment: @F.Hauri , `awk` popped in my mind before `xargs` could. I do not have any performance benefits of one over another. OP is free to use that.